# Extend LVM partition created on a raw device

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, lvm

My Ubuntu 14.04 is running as a Hyper-V guest. So far it had a 140 GB extra virtual "data" disk (in addition to the main Ubuntu OS image). I have now resized the disk in Hyper-V to 200 GB. How do I extend the LVM volume that has been created on this disk to take up all available space if the volume has been created on a raw device (without partitioning the device first and adding the disk partition to LVM)? All answers I could find come from the assumption that the device has been partitioned and a partition has been added to LVM (an now a new partition can be created and added to LVM again).

The way the volume has been set up:

```
# pvcreate /dev/sdb
# vgextend ubuntubase-vg /dev/sdb
# lvcreate -n lvol0 -L 140G ubuntubase-vg
# mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/ubuntubase--vg-lvol0
```

`fdisk` already shows that `/dev/sdb` has an updated size of 200 GB, but no partitions:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 214.7 GB, 214748364800 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 26108 cylinders, total 419430400 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/sdb doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

`pvdisplay` still shows the old 140GB:

```
--- Physical volume ---
PV Name               /dev/sdb
VG Name               ubuntubase-vg
PV Size               140.00 GiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
Allocatable           yes (but full)
PE Size               4.00 MiB
Total PE              35839
Free PE               0
Allocated PE          35839
PV UUID               XZ2sei-NRnA-IzF1-EQAK-fq9m-VTHS-Q0zRx6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should extend the physical volume to use up all the available space on the disk:

```
pvresize /dev/sdb
```

See `man 8 pvresize`.

After that you have to resize the logical volume:

```
lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/ubuntubase-vg/lvol0
```

And extend the filesystem:

```
resize2fs /dev/ubuntubase-vg/lvol0
```